# pip install pyaudio error cl.exe failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, pip, installation

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cybercry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tder68r3\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cybercry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0p059g11-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    c:\python27\include\pyconfig.h(117): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cybercry\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-tder68r3\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cybercry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0p059g11-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cybercry\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tder68r3\pyaudio\
```

Comment: Seriously? You are expecting us to read that messy bunch of code? Please format code and error messages as code and normal text as normal text.

Comment: @Binarus There was no text. He just dumped the error output.

Comment: Text should be added to this to clarify the issue and then there can be the error output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prebuilt wheels of [PyAudio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio) are currently available for Python 2.7 and 3.4-3.6. If you don't want to use Python 3.6 and want to install PyAudio in 3.7 you have to compile and install PortAudio and PyAudio from sources. See the instructions at

http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html

https://smaudet.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/building-pyaudio-on-windows-7-x64-using-the-free-msvc-toolchains/