# I get an error when trying to install PyAudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

When I try to install PyAudio in CMD with `py -m pip install PyAudio` I get this:

```
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
  Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jiney\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8j63lfi\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eik80aaq\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jiney\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h8j63lfi\\PyAudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eik80aaq\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jiney\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h8j63lfi\PyAudio\
```

I am extremely confused here and I really don't know what to do, when I use the same method using py -m install (package) it works but just not with PyAudio.
Any replies are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: As per the above error message:

extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

You need MS Visual C++ 14.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install pyaudio error cl.exe failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511423/pip-install-pyaudio-error-cl-exe-failed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283840/i-cant-install-pyaudio-on-my-python-how-to-do-it

Answer (score 0):

It appears you need to install Microsoft Visual C++ as per this line in the error message:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. 
Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```